# Render a dropdown inside extjs grid and change other columns text on dropdown change

Tags: extjs

I am working on extjs to create a grid where first column is a dropdown that user sees. When user change the dropdown, the other two columns of the grid gets populated.

For eg,  Let the columns be

Name, City, State

Let the first column dropdown has record "John", "Carol".

Always this dropdown should be shown to user and when they choose either John or Carol,
the City and State values in the row changes.

Let me know how this can be done. I am aware of the rowedit where clicking a cell, changes the text to dropdown. In my case, I want the dropdown to be shown by default, and changing the dropdown populates other column.

I did this raw approach

```
{
     text : 'Name',
     dataIndex : "Name",
     renderer : function(value, cell) {
        return '<select><option>John</option><option>Carol</option></select>';
     }
```

}

But don't know how to connect an event change to this dropdown to modify other column values.

Also is this the way to do it or we have a better way ?

Thanks,

Comment: Which version of Extjs are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for component cells. have a look on this

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?148064-Component-Column-Components-in-Grid-Cells